# Is there a way in Javascript to determine if no elements are in focus?

Tags: javascript

I'm building some hotkeys into a page of my HTML:

```
   $(document).bind('keypress', function (e) {
        var event = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

        if (event == LETTER_P) {
            // go to another page
        }
    }
```

But the problem is that if they are entering text on the page (in a textbox element, etc) and hit the letter 'P', they are off to another page.  I only want the redirection to happen if they are not in any elements.

Comment: Oh yeah, any way I can do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.activeElement` is supported by all major browsers these days. If no element is in focus then `activeElement` will return the document body, so:

```
if (document.activeElement === document.body) {
    // Nothing is in focus
}
```

Comment: I like this check, I can wrap all the keychecks within this to make sure.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function (e) {
    var event = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

    if (event == LETTER_P && document.activeElement.tagName == "input") {
        // go to another page
    }
}
```

My addition to your code doesn't require any library.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $('input:focus, select:focus').length){
   // there is a focused element which would respond to a keypress
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:focus` selector in jQuery.

```
if ( $( "input:focus, textarea:focus" ).length ) {
   // there is a focused element
}
```

Comment: How "Heavy" is that call?  Is that parsing the entire DOM or is there a quicker way?

Comment: It is parsing the entire DOM, but you can make it quicker by changing it to `$( "input:focus, textarea:focus" )` so it only checks inputs and textareas.